# Error running RGA on AWS Docker to get Google Analytics real-time info

Tags: r, google-analytics

We are trying to run a simple R job that read Google Analytics and saves data to a googlesheets, but we are getting this error:

```
Error: interactive() is not TRUE
```

The job runs on a docker on Amazon AWS.

Our code looks like:

```
library(RGA)
library(openxlsx)
library(googlesheets)

authorize(username='username',token = "apps.googleusercontent.com.json")

gs_auth(token = "GoogleSheetsToken.rds")

ga_data = get_realtime(MY_ID, metrics = "metric"
                    ,dimensions = "dimension"
)

x = gs_title("MY SHEET")
gs_edit_cells(ss = x, ws = "GA", input = ga_data, anchor = "A1", col_names = F)
```

How can we make this happens?

Regards.